# 301 Old Url to New in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, web-config

I'm trying to use web.config to redirect old url to new on some site
I want to exactly redirect https://www.example.com/phone/ to https://www.example.com/all-phones-list

```
        <rule name="Redirect to url" stopProcessing="true">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="example.com/phone/" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="www.example.com/phone/" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example/all-phones-list" redirectType="Permanent"/>
        </rule>
```

The code above worked, but the challenge is, links like https://www.example.com/phone/infinix-note-5/ also redirect to https://www.example.com/all-phones-list

Please what Am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the pattern to check the end using "$" otherwise it will match any longer string as well:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="example.com/phone/$" />
```